# load dataSource from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring + Hibernate for a school project.

Everything is working, i am able to get data from the database but i have a question about the database settings.

Is it possible to replace the `getDataSource` method for a config file? Example application.properties.

How can I implement it in my config file? And is there a specified location for config files?

This is my AppConfig.java

```
package com.exstodigital.photofactory;

import com.exstodigital.photofactory.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        // Models
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.exstodigital.photofactory.model");

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("********");
        dataSource.setUsername("********");
        dataSource.setPassword("********");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: @Zeus when i look into the logs i see Tomcat is running on 8080, so I guess Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Update your `server.xml` to have the following lines, it is same like what you are doing in the getDataSource() but datasource is configured at the server level.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" 
      global="jdbc/MyDB" 
      auth="Container" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UserDB" 
      username="pankaj" 
      password="pankaj123"        
      maxActive="100" 
      maxIdle="20" 
      minIdle="5" 
      maxWait="10000"/>
```

in your getDataSource just pull this datasource using the following lines of code and return it.

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyLocalDB");
```

ref :http://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java

Comment: I don't use XML files for configuration.

Comment: @Yooouuri This is a configuration at the server level, the server will take care of maintaining your connections to the database. all you do is get it from the server using the java line that I wrote..

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done.

> first make a config file:give it a name in my case it is prop.properties and provide all details in key value pairs

```
host=127.0.0.1
port=****
dbuser=****
dbpwd=****
dbname=****
```

> then create a property object and file input stream

```
public static Properties prop = new Properties();
    static InputStream input = null;
```

> load the property file by providing it's location. i have my file in /opt folder

```
static{
            try {                 
                input = new FileInputStream("/opt/prop.properties");
                prop.load(input);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

> now fetch all the property by providing the keys

```
prop.getProperty("host");
prop.getProperty("port");
prop.getProperty("dbuser");
prop.getProperty("dbpwd");
prop.getProperty("dbname");
```

> you can keep the file in the desired location. but sure to provide the
>   relative path in the program.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can

Try something like

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String jdbcURl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

@Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "your package" });
        return sessionFactory;
    }

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcURl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource

}
```

So your application.properties will have the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = {whatever you want to put}
spring.datasource.username = {Your username}
spring.datasource.password = {Your password}
```

Comment: OP wnts the data source pulled from the config file.

Comment: Aah, the whole dataSource.. my bad

Comment: But how is a bean going to be stored in properties file?

Comment: Its a way, but SHOULD i use a config file for holding the database connection?

Comment: @NickDiv i want to read the values from a config file, the method i dont care really but i want to do it the right way!

Comment: @Yooouuri Defintiely, i have infact used it in all my projects. I would further say go ahead and encrypt the password as well. But its upto you.

Comment: My properties file looks like spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username should the sessionFactory take that information?

Comment: How you declare that information in your properties file is upto you, the information will be used by the dataSource and dataSource in turn will be used by sessionFactory
I am assuming you are doing something like this:
sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());

Comment: @Yooouuri Please check the updated answer, this should make things a bit more clearer

Comment: @NickDiv what about the ``dataSource()`` method?

Comment: @Yooouuri Sorry the getDataSource was actually supposed to be called dataSource()